# printer spool monitor

Tags: mfc, printing, visual-c++, driver

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [printer spool monitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345371/printer-spool-monitor)

I want to capture following attributes from print server spool on print of any page. i am able to capture 3 of 4 attributes through these APIs(FindFirstPrinterChangeNotification, FindNextPrinterChangeNotification). but still i am not able to get data of file(so i can keep the thumbnail of this file by page by page)

Computer Name - DONE

User Name - DONE

File Name -DONE

Data of file -???

please suggest me some solution to achieve this.

Comment: Exact duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345371/printer-spool-monitor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345371/printer-spool-monitor)