# printer spool monitor

Tags: windows, printing, driver

I want to capture following attributes from print server spool on print of any page. i am able to capture 
3 of 4 attributes through these APIs(FindFirstPrinterChangeNotification, 
FindNextPrinterChangeNotification). but still i am not able to get data of file(so i can keep the thumbnail of this file by page by page)

1. Computer Name - DONE
2. User Name - DONE
3. File Name -DONE
4. Data of file -???

please suggest me some solution to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

[Papercut](http://www.papercut.com/) does this. My Previous employer has been using it in a large site for some time now for monitoring (i.e. the other features are turned off)